# Store entered data when leaving checkout page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session-state

This is a problem all of us can connect to:

- We fill out our checkout info in a webshop, and then want to check something in our basket. We go back to our basket, see everything is fine, and we go back to the checkout. **Now all the fields we filled out are empty**

I would like to implement a solution where the webapplication stores the information, so when the user comes back - it is stored. The same goes if some refresh happens, then everything is stored.

I've considered the following ways of implementing this:

- Using jQuery: Calling a WebMethod when a user has filled out
  something and store this in a session
- Catching some leave-page event (is that possible?), and iterate my
  fields and save those in a session

Are these good solutions? Is there other and better ways to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where to store?**

You could either store the data locally or on the server. For storing locally, you could use html5 localstorage or any of the available shims as a fallback. Eg: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js#readme

**When to store?**

Options are either whenever the user enters some data. This could be onChange or preferably onBlur. Or you could save every 10 seconds. Though am not sure how that will be better...

You could also hook into the [onBeforeUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onbeforeunload) event to alert the user that they may loose their data if they leave without saving. And in general provide a button to explicitly save that data.

As such, you may not want to store sensitive information...

Btw, SO already does this. When you are posting an answer and you refresh the page, you get the default Browser prompt alerting you to what you are about to do. Even if you do choose to leave, you see the same page back, with most of the answer still there! Cuz, SO is posting the contents of the answer periodically... You can check for yourself using Firebug...

Comment: Awesome! Decided to implement the solution you linked to. Works great...

Thanks a lot :) Great solution.